# Powershell Core Invoke-RestMethod giving Unexpected character ('M' (code 77)): expected a valid value

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable, powershell-core

This is driving me crazy I have spent the last few days trying to find some answers in the forums but not seen anything which can help me here. Maybe I am just blind.

Here is my problem. I am trying to update one of our Confluence Wiki pages using the API provided to update a page.

I have three scripts or functions:

1. Deploy script or controller script which calls the Create and with the response (Json) calls Update
2. Create Confluence Json
3. Update page

This is Create function

```
function Create-WikiPage
 [CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [int]$CurrentPageRevisionNumber
) 
    # Creates the ID for new page
$NextPageID=$CurrentPageRevisionNumber + 1

# Creates the json body of the Wiki page
$ToolsPage= @{
    "version"= @{
        "number"= $NextPageID
    };
    "title"= "Windows Build Agent Tool Set";
    "type"= "page";
    "body"= @{
        "storage"= @{
            "value"= "<p><table><tr><th>Vendor-Application</th><th>Version</th></tr></table></p>";
            "representation"= "storage"
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json


$ToolsPage
}
```

The update function looks like this:

```
Update-WikiPage {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Server,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Username,

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$Password,

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [long]$PageId,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $Data
)
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls12, Tls11'

$Encoded =  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$($Username):$Password"))
$Header = @{"Authorization" = "Basic $Encoded"
        }     
Write-Information ($Data | Out-String)
$Data.GetType()

# Updates the Wiki page
Invoke-RestMethod "$($Server)/rest/api/content/$($PageId)" -Method PUT -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Data -PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect 
}
```

As you can see I have get a print out of the JSon object as part of the update function. This is the print out:

```
    {
  "version": {
    "number": 9
  },
  "body": {
    "storage": {
      "value": "<p><table><tr><th>Vendor-Application</th><th>Version</th></tr></table></p>",
      "representation": "storage"
    }
  },
  "title": "Windows Build Agent Tool Set",
  "type": "page"
}
```

And this is the powershell error I get:

```
VERBOSE: received -byte response of content type application/json
Invoke-RestMethod : {"statusCode":500,"message":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('M' (code 77)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.restapi.filters.LimitingRequestFilter$1@6b6831ec; line: 1, column: 2]"}
At C:\Users\ChildsC\Documents\Git\PowerShellModules\Wiki\Update-WikiPage.ps1:65 char:2
+     Invoke-RestMethod "$($Server)/rest/api/content/$($PageId)" -Metho ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Method: PUT, Re...ication/json
}:HttpRequestMessage) [Invoke-RestMethod], HttpResponseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

**EDIT**

I have noticed that he issue happens when I am passing the json object from the Create Json -> Deploy -> Update
if I create the json in the Deploy script and pass it to the Update it works without issues.

Comment: Looks like an issue with `plugins.restapi.filters.LimitingRequestFilter$1@6b6831ec; line: 1, column: 2`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I have noticed that he issue happens when I am passing the json object from the Create Json -> Deploy -> Update
if I create the json in the Deploy script and pass it to the Update it works without issues. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

So for this it turns out I was an idiot. And no-one else would see the problem because I did not post the complete script.

Earlier in the Create function I had a line to post params to the console:

```
$PsBoundParameters | Out-String
```

So when I thought the script was returning only the $ToolsPage value it was actually also returning another object with it.

Therefore the reason why the Update Script is because I am explicitly passing on the $ToolsPage variable.

I found this out by setting Parameters, which should hold the value of the object to $Global:variable_name and then compared the values from my console.